# How to pass json data in xamarin forms web view android side

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-webview

I am using xamarin forms webview and want to pass username and password json body with url like below.

[image]

I Implement Hybrid webview in xamarin forms

My PCL Code:

```
public class HybridWebView : WebView
    {
        Action<string> action;
        public EventHandler<bool> WebNavigating;


        public void RegisterAction (Action<string> callback)
        {
            action = callback;
        }

        public void Cleanup ()
        {
            action = null;
        }

        public void InvokeAction (string data)
        {
            if (action == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {
                return;
            }
            action.Invoke (data);
        }
    }
```

My Android HybridWebViewRenderer Code :

```
 public class HybridWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<HybridWebView, Android.Webkit.WebView> 
{

    Context _context;

    public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            var webView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(webView,e,this));
            SetNativeControl(webView);
        }
    }
}

public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    const string JavaScriptFunction = "function invokeCSharpAction(data){jsBridge.invokeAction(data);}";
    public Android.Webkit.WebView _webView;
    public Android.Webkit.WebView WebView
    {
        get
        {
            return _webView;
        }
    }

    public ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> _element;

    public MyWebViewClient(Android.Webkit.WebView view, ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> element, HybridWebViewRenderer x)
    {
        _webView = view;
        _element = element;

        if (_element.OldElement != null)
        {
            _webView.RemoveJavascriptInterface("jsBridge");
            var hybridWebView = _element.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            hybridWebView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (_element.NewElement != null)
        {
            _webView.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(x), "jsBridge");

            string url = "https://Myspecific.com/Account/MobileLogin";
           string postData = "{\"UserName\":\"User1\",\"Password\":\"pass123\",\"RememberMe\":false}";
            _webView.PostUrl(url, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData));
        }
    }
```

output:
It shows wrong username and password

Please help...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the "wrong username and password"?

Comment: if passing wrong username and password, then service return login page otherwise home page.

Comment: currently it redirect to login page. it should be navigate to home page